# Is this the correct circuit for a Sourcing Digital Output

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, opto-isolator, output

My objective is simple:

1. Let the user connect any reasonable voltage to SOURCE0 (3.3-48V) and get that voltage at OUTPUT0 when BACKUP0 goes high from my MCU (3.3V signal)

[image]

I've seen some examples including an additional transistor placed after the emitter of the opto, is this necessary?

Also should the grounds on each side of the opto be different?

This circuit will be used in an industrial setting. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've seen some examples including an additional transistor placed after the emitter of the opto, is this necessary?

It could be used as a buffer. Maybe the opto doesn't have enough current drive capability for the next stage, so an extra transistor with higher current rating can be added to your output.

> Also should the grounds on each side of the opto be different?

Usually, you use an opto to isolate two different circuits (high voltage 
vs low voltage) and prevent one from damaging/interfering with the other. But they can certainly be the same ground though.

Comment: Thanks, in reality the ground of the external device never needs to be connected to my circuit right? All I am doing is interrupting its positive voltage path right?

Comment: @wgthompson Correct, you don't have to connect the two grounds together. But you do need ground from your circuit to connect on the left side of your opto (diode) and the external supply's ground to be, as shown, on the right side of the opto.

Comment: Thanks so much, but just to confirm, can I remove the ground on J12 so that the only connection to the external device is OUTPUT0? Just making sure the common of the external device doesnt need to have a connection to the gnd of my circuit. Thanks again

Comment: @wgthompson the common of the external source needs to be connected to the lower leg of R18. The problem in your schematic is that you have pin 2 of U11 and the lower of R18 tied to what you call "GND". Pin 2 of U11 is connected to the ground terminal from a 3.3V MCU, let's call that GND. The lower leg of R18 needs to connect to the ground of the external source, let's call that "common". Now you don't have to tie GND and the Common together somewhere  in your circuit (could be done though) but the Common does need to be present in the lower leg of R18.

Comment: got it thanks so much. I have edited the circuit above to reflect this change